# document get element not executing in my begin game function

Tags: javascript

For some reason when I try to change the src element in the begin game function it does not want to change. The src location is correct and I've tried the setTimeout as well. Is there a way to pause the code but for it to run it Synchronized? The begin function is below pasted again to make it easier to view. Is there a way to use setTimeout without it running EVERYTHING at once?

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="scripts/simon.js" async></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/simon.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <h1><u>Difficulty</u></h1>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="difficulty" onclick="setDifficulty(this.innerHTML)">Easy</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="difficulty" onclick="setDifficulty(this.innerHTML)">Medium</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="difficulty" onclick="setDifficulty(this.innerHTML)">Hard</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="difficulty" onclick="setDifficulty(this.innerHTML)">Xtreme</a>
    <button id="start" onclick="startup()">Start</button>
</div>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
<div class="infoBar">
    <img src="assets/icons/nothing.png"></img>
    <img src="assets/icons/nothing.png"></img>
    <img src="assets/icons/nothing.png"></img>
    <img src="assets/icons/nothing.png"></img>
    <img src="assets/icons/nothing.png"></img>
</div>
<div class="game-container">
    <img class="redButton" id="red" src="assets/icons/red.png"></img>
    <img class="blueButton" id="blue" src="assets/icons/blue.png"></img>
    <img class="greenButton" id="green" src="assets/icons/green.png"></img>
    <img class="yellowButton" id="yellow" src="assets/icons/yellow.png"></img>
    <div class="logo">
        <img class="logoButton" src="assets/icons/logo.png"></img>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="scripts/simon.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var currentLvl;
var playerinput;
var levelOfDiff = 0;

function sleep(miliseconds){
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var currentTime = currentDate.getTime();
    while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()){
    }
}

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Start";
  }

  function setDifficulty(diff){
    if(diff == "Easy"){
        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Start Easy Mode";
        levelOfDiff = 3;
    }
    if(diff == "Medium"){
        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Start Medium Mode";
        levelOfDiff = 5;
    }
    if(diff == "Hard"){
        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Start Hard Mode";
        levelOfDiff = 7;
    }
    if(diff == "Xtreme"){
        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Start Xtreme Mode";
        levelOfDiff = 10;
    }
  } 

  function startup(){
    if(levelOfDiff != 0){
        var mainSequence = [levelOfDiff];
        beginGame(mainSequence);
    }
    else{
        alert("Please choose a difficulty");
    }
  }

  function beginGame(mainSequence){
      for(var x = 0;x<levelOfDiff;x++){
        mainSequence[x] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * Math.ceil(4));
      }
      console.log(mainSequence);
    for(var y=0;y<levelOfDiff;y++){
        if(mainSequence[y] == 1){
            console.log("change");
            document.getElementById("green").src = "../assets/icons/greenClick.png";
            sleep(1000);
            console.log("back");
            document.getElementById("green").src = "../assets/icons/green.png";
        }
        if(mainSequence[y] == 2){
            console.log("change");
            document.getElementById("red").src = "../assets/icons/redClick.png";
            sleep(1000);
            console.log("back");
            document.getElementById("red").src = "../assets/icons/red.png";     
        }
        if(mainSequence[y] == 3){
            console.log("change");
            document.getElementById("blue").src = "../assets/icons/BlueClick.png";
            sleep(1000);
            console.log("back");
            document.getElementById("blue").src = "../assets/icons/blue.png";
        }
        if(mainSequence[y] == 4){
            console.log("change");
            document.getElementById("yellow").src = "../assets/icons/yellowClick.png";
            sleep(1000);
            console.log("back");
            document.getElementById("yellow").src = "../assets/icons/yellow.png";
        }
        sleep(1000);
      }
  }
/*
    Green is 1
    Red is 2
    Blue is 3
    Yellow is 4
*/
```

Problem in JS

```
function beginGame(mainSequence) {
  for (var x = 0; x < levelOfDiff; x++) {
    mainSequence[x] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * Math.ceil(4));
  }
  console.log(mainSequence);
  for (var y = 0; y < levelOfDiff; y++) {
    if (mainSequence[y] == 1) {
      console.log("change");
      document.getElementById("green").src = "../assets/icons/greenClick.png";
      sleep(1000);
      console.log("back");
      document.getElementById("green").src = "../assets/icons/green.png";
    }
    if (mainSequence[y] == 2) {
      console.log("change");
      document.getElementById("red").src = "../assets/icons/redClick.png";
      sleep(1000);
      console.log("back");
      document.getElementById("red").src = "../assets/icons/red.png";
    }
    if (mainSequence[y] == 3) {
      console.log("change");
      document.getElementById("blue").src = "../assets/icons/BlueClick.png";
      sleep(1000);
      console.log("back");
      document.getElementById("blue").src = "../assets/icons/blue.png";
    }
    if (mainSequence[y] == 4) {
      console.log("change");
      document.getElementById("yellow").src = "../assets/icons/yellowClick.png";
      sleep(1000);
      console.log("back");
      document.getElementById("yellow").src = "../assets/icons/yellow.png";
    }
    sleep(1000);
  }
}  
/*
    Green is 1
    Red is 2
    Blue is 3
    Yellow is 4
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You've stumbled on one of the differences between JS and most other well-known programming languages. In JavaScript, everything in the same scope runs at the same time. Therefore `sleep(1000)` doesn't actually do anything because it just runs alongside everything else without blocking.

I'd recommend looking into [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but if I understand your needs correctly, `setTimeout` could work. Try something like this:

```
// This line will run
document.getElementById("green").src = "../assets/icons/greenClick.png";

// Then this will set a waiting time of one second
setTimeout(function() {
  // This line will run after 1 second
  document.getElementById("green").src = "../assets/icons/green.png";
},1000)
```

Comment: Ive inputed what you said, it changes the image but it does it all at once, not timed

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want it to change the src image 1 after the other. Change 1 src wait 1 sec then change the next one

Comment: Do you want to keep changing or change only once? The code above does exactly what you need, but maybe 1 second is just too little for you. Set it to 5000 for example and see how it feels.